# Using AVAssetReader and copyNextSampleBuffer without polling

Tags: multithreading, avfoundation, avassetreader

I am using `AVAssetReader` to read audio data from a file, on a secondary thread. Every code example I have seen has at the heart of it a loop like this:

```
    while (assetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) 
    {    
        // ...
        buffer = [theAssetReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
        // ...
    }
```

(or the Swift equivalent). My question is, does `copyNextSampleBuffer` block while waiting for data from the `AVAsset`, or does it return `NULL` if the data is not yet available? If the latter, then we have a polling loop, which is poor practice, burning CPU cycles while repeatedly checking `status`. The documentation for `copyNextSampleBuffer` doesn't say whether or not it blocks the thread while waiting. I also can't tell if it attempts to return immediately with whatever data it has available, or fails/blocks unless it has enough data for a buffer of a certain minimum size.

Comment: `copyNextSampleBuffer` blocks and returns `NULL` on EOF.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Actually it is! See my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I should have thought to look there. I see the header file also documents the values of `status` which are not documented elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is actually documented (always a pleasant surprise). The header file for `copyNextSampleBuffer` says

> Copies the next sample buffer for the output synchronously.

And `copyNextSampleBuffer` is documented to return `NULL` when no more samples can be read on `EOF` `status` will be set to `AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted` 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreaderoutput/1385732-copynextsamplebuffer

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreaderstatus?language=objc